# How to Remove curly brackets and remane the key value of JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I am getting output like this

```json
{
  "intent": "P&P_Purchase",
  "value1": {
    "date1": "30-Dec-19",
    "prd_desc": "NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG)",
    "qty": "18MT",
    "inv_no": "NRKT07003160"
  },
  "value2": {
    "date1": "25-Dec-19",
    "prd_desc": "NEEM UREA IMP (45 KG)",
    "qty": "18MT",
    "inv_no": "NRKT07003107"
  },
  "value3": {
    "date1": "19-Dec-19",
    "prd_desc": "DAP IMP",
    "qty": "20MT",
    "inv_no": "NRKT07003058"
  },
  "value4": {
    "date1": "16-Dec-19",
    "prd_desc": "NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG)",
    "qty": "18MT",
    "inv_no": "NRKT07003043"
  },
  "value5": {
    "date1": "30-Nov-19",
    "prd_desc": "NEEM UREA IMP (45 KG)",
    "qty": "54MT",
    "inv_no": "NRKT07002921"
  },
  "value6": null,
  "value7": null,
  "value8": null,
  "value9": null,
  "value10": null
}
```

so, i want to remove all inner curl brackets as well rename the value like

**{"intent":"P&P_Purchase","value1":Date:30-Dec-19,Product:NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG),Quantity:18MT,inv_no:NRKT07003160,"value2":Date:31-Dec-19,Product:NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG),Quantity:18MT,inv_no:NRKT07003160,"value3":Date:01-Jan-19,Product:NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG),Quantity:18MT,inv_no:NRKT07003160,"value4":Date:02-Jan-19,Product:NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG),Quantity:18MT,inv_no:NRKT07003160,"value5":Date:03-Jan-19,Product:NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG),Quantity:18MT,inv_no:NRKT07003160,"value6":null,"value7":null,"value8":null,"value9":null,"value10":null}**

Now, I am trying to do with this code but i am not able to achieve it

````
    ```var data = {"token" : token,"serviceID" : serviceID,"P_USERID" : P_USERID };
var sdata = JSON.stringify(data);
const options = {
       method: 'POST',
       uri: 'http://chatbotWebservice/resources/webservice/service' ,
       body: JSON.parse(sdata) ,
       json: true
       }
    return request(options)
        .then( body => {
            var unit =  body
            unit.intent = "P&P_Purchase"
            unit.value1 = unit.level3purpay[0]
            console.log(unit.level3purpay[0].prd_desc)
            unit.value2 = unit.level3purpay[1]
            unit.value3 = unit.level3purpay[2]
            unit.value4 = unit.level3purpay[3]
            unit.value5 = unit.level3purpay[4]
            unit.value6 = null
            unit.value7 = null
            unit.value8 = null
            unit.value9 = null
            unit.value10 = null
            delete unit.level3purpay
            const unit_value = {
            date1: "Date",
            prd_desc: "Product",
            qty: "Quantity",
            inv_no: "inv_no"
            };
            const unit2 = Object.entries(unit)
            .map(([key, value]) => `${labels[key]}:${value}`)
            .join();
            var unit3 = JSON.stringify(unit2)
            console.log(unit3)
      conv.ask(unit2);
          })
          .catch( err => {
           console.error( err );
           conv.ask('Something went wrong. What should I do now?');
             });
          })
````

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: If you want to flatten the JSON, have a look into a flattener. Like this one: https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf please read this to get used to json. same keys is not good practice

Comment: Your desired result is no longer machine-readable, so why would you want that?

Answer (score 0):

try a recursive function!

Pseudocode:

```
cleanjson = {};
function clearBrakets(json,parent_name){
  keys = getKeys(json);
  for(i = 0; i < keys.lenght; i ++){
   if(json[keys[i]].type == array){
    clearBrakets(json[keys[i]],keys[i]);
   }else{
    cleanjson[parent_name + keys[i]] = json[i];
   }
  }
}
```

**WARNING:** be careful with nested duplicated key names ex:

`{obj1:{value="aa",name="cc"},obj2:{value="bb"}}`

will output

`{value="bb",name="cc"}` instead of `{value="aa",name="cc",value="bb"}`

try adding the parent name:

`{obj1_value="aa",obj1_name="cc",obj2_value="bb"}`